# "TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable" error with tensorflow Estimator

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

I have a procedurally generated (infinite) data source and am trying to use this as input to the high-level Tensorflow `Estimator` to train a image-based 3D object detector.

I set up the Dataset just as in the Tensorflor Estimator [Quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator#complete_neural_network_source_code), and my `dataset_input_fn` returns a tuple of features and labels `Tensor`'s, just as the [`Estimator.train`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L264-L266) function specifies, and how this [tutorial shows](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#using_high-level_apis), but I am getting an error when trying to call the train function:

`TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.`

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
    def data_generator():
        """
        Generator for image (features) and ground truth object positions (labels)

        Sample an image and object positions from a procedurally generated data source
        """
        while True:
            source.step()  # generate next data point

            object_ground_truth = source.get_ground_truth() # list of 9 floats
            cam_img = source.get_cam_frame()  # image (224, 224, 3) 
            yield (cam_img, object_ground_truth)

    def dataset_input_fn():
        """
        Tensorflow `Dataset` object from generator
        """

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, (tf.uint8, tf.float32), \
            (tf.TensorShape([224, 224, 3]), tf.TensorShape([9])))
        dataset = dataset.batch(16)

        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

        features, labels = iterator.get_next()
        return features, labels

    def main():
        """
        Estimator [from Keras model](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators#creating_estimators_from_keras_models) 

        Try to call `est_vgg.train()` leads to the error
        """
        ....
        est_vgg16 = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=keras_vgg16)
        est_vgg16.train(input_fn=dataset_input_fn, steps=10)
        ....
```

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/matwilso/rock_detector/blob/79b092f261aaf31e5088bcc8a03ee925fe5cda2e/rock_detector.py#L118)

(note: things are named differently from this question)

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rock_detector.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
  File "./rock_detector.py", line 117, in main
    est_vgg16.train(input_fn=dataset_input_fn, steps=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 302, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 711, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 694, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py", line 145, in model_fn
    labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py", line 92, in _clone_and_build_model
    keras_model, features)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py", line 58, in _create_ordered_io
    for key in estimator_io_dict:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 505, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

Comment: I think you just want: `get_next = iterator.get_next();   est_vgg16.train(input_fn=get_next, steps=10`, but I don't use keras so I'm not totally familiar with the `.train` function in use there.

Comment: Can you please share the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: Updated post with stack trace. It is a bit hard to understand what is going on under the hood with the high-level api. I got it to work with about as much effort by switching to the lower-level interface for tf and just "feeding" with the generator manually.  The nice thing about higher level api, though, is that it handles all training and details and can probably optimize processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your input function return a dictionary of features like this:

```py
def dataset_input_fn():
  ...
  features, labels = iterator.get_next()
  return {'image': features}, labels
```

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks.  As a note for future visitors, I also had to change `tf.uint8` to `tf.float32` in `dataset_input_fn`.