# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

In tensor flow, I have got a tensor with 512 rows and 2 columns. What I want to do is that: filter column 2 of the tensor on the basis of unique values of column 1 and then for each unique value (of column 1) process corresponding values of column 2 in the inner loop.

So, as an example, I have got a 2-dimensional tensor, value (after evaluating in a session) of which looks like following:

```
[[ 509,  270],
[ 533,  568],
[ 472,  232],
..., 
[   6,  276],
[ 331,  165],
[ 401, 1144]]

509, 533, 472 ... are elements of column1 and 270, 568, 232,... are elements of column 2.
```

Is there a way that I can `define` following 2 steps within a graph (not while executing the session):

```
  get unique values of column1
  for each `unique_value` in column1:
      values_in_column2 = values in column2 corresponding to `unique_value` (filter column2 according to unique_value`)
      some_function(values_in_column2)
```

I can do above steps while running the session but I would like to define the above 2 steps in a graph - which I can run in session after defining many subsequent steps.

Is there any way to do this? Appreciate any kind of help in this regard.
Here is pseudo code for what I want to do.

```
      tensor1 = tf.stack([column1, column2], axis = 1)
      column1 = tensor1[0, :]
      unique_column1, unique_column1_indexes = tf.unique(column1)
      for unique_column1_value in unique_column1:
          column1_2_indexes = tf.where(column1 == unique_column1_value)
          corresponding_column2_values = tensor1[column1_2_indexes][:, 1]
```

But as of now it gives an error:

```
  TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

at the following line:
      for unique_column1_value in unique_column1.

I have followed this question: ["TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable" error with tensorflow Estimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241010/typeerror-tensor-object-is-not-iterable-error-with-tensorflow-estimator) which does not apply to me.
I understand that I need to use [while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) but I don't know how.

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** There is a solution for when `column1` is sorted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4614). Note that this is also a feature request for the more general version, but is closed for inactivity. The sorted version solution is like:

```
column1 = tf.constant([1,2,2,2,3,3,4])
column2 = tf.constant([5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
tensor1 = tf.stack([column1, column2], axis = 1)
unique_column1, unique_column1_indices, counts = tf.unique_with_counts(column1)
unique_ix = tf.cumsum(tf.pad(counts,[[1,0]]))[:-1]
output = tf.gather(tensor1, unique_ix)
```

which outputs: [[ 1,  5][ 2,  6][ 3,  9][ 4, 11]]

Comment: Hi @Kane C, thank you for your attempt but this does not answer my question. In simple terms, I want all the column2 values (as a tensor or a list) corresponding to each value of column 1. I just checked that this does not do that. It was a nice attempt though.

Comment: Problem is with `unique_column1_indices`. It does not retain the original indices of `tensor 1`. It returns the indices of sorted values of column 1 which but for duplicate elements will have the same index. Which is not what I want.

Comment: @Sumit : Yes, I see your point. Looks like there is a closed feature request for this. In this link (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4614), there is a solution for a sorted tensor.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the above info...hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Kane, in your example I want an output like: [[5], [6,7,8], [9,10], [11]]. I needed all the column 2 values corresponding to a column 1 value and not just the first one.

Comment: @Sumit: Your desired output is not a valid shape for a tensor, so I don't think that what you want is possible with tensor ops

Comment: Can't we return a variable size tensor in each iteration of [while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) loop? column 2 values corresponding to each value of column 1.

Comment: Maybe? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with `tf.while_loop`. Maybe someone else will jump in. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Kane, I am also not familiar with it. But hoping and trying to get a solution using `tf.while_loop`.